# How to stop Netbeans IDE 8.1 from inserting extra backward slash "\"?

Tags: java, netbeans, clipboard, copy-paste, backslash

I have a content in Windows 7 Clipboard:

```
\u0643\u064a\u0641\u0020\u062d\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0645
```

When I paste it between a string double quotes; it goes like this:

```
"\\u0643\\u064a\\u0641\\u0020\\u062d\\u0627\\u0644\\u0643\\u0645"
```

I know it is a feature. But it annoy me in this situation.

How to disable this feature in NetBeans IDE 8.1?

Answer (score 3):

I found an easy and fast workaround for it;

Copy the content you want as usual. To paste the content into NetBeans IDE without inserting an extra backward slash; do the following:

1- Comment out the line of code you want to insert the content into:
`//String strUnicode = "";`

2- Paste the content as usual between the double quotes:
`//String strUnicode = "\u0643\u064a\u0641\u0020\u062d\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0645";`

3- Uncomment the line of code:
`String strUnicode = "\u0643\u064a\u0641\u0020\u062d\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0645";`